# Why are beta-ketoacids better at decarboxylation than gamma or delta?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

My book claims that beta-ketoacids and beta-dicarboxylic acids are better at decarboxylating than their gamma and delta counterparts. **Why is that?**

I would assume that since gamma and delta keto-acids make a larger ring intermediate (less ring strain) and thus the energy barrier for reaching that intermediate would be lower...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has to do with the stability of the electrons that are ejected from the bond that breaks. In B-ketoacids, the electrons can resonate onto the oxygen and form an enol/enolate intermediate, which is much more stable than forming a carbanion on a gamma or delta ketoacid (because there is nowhere for the electrons to go other than go on the carbon atom that participates in the bond-breaking event).

[image]